# Not able to find "Use Custom Web Server"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, web-applications, windows-7

I just installed Windows 7 on my development machine, along with Visual Studio 2008. Everything works fine, except for one thing - I have lost my "Use Custom Web Server" setting!

What am I missing? :|

Action shot: http://i28.tinypic.com/5l2re1.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to have SP1 installed...

Comment: This restored the option again for me even with Web Application Projects. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To use a Custom Server, your project must be a Web Site Project, not a Web Application Project.  There is no conversion option between these types, so you must create a new project of the Web Site Project type.

See [Create a New IIS 7.0 Web Site or Application Project](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/387/using-visual-studio-2008-with-iis-70/) on the Learn IIS site.

Comment: Yes, that enabled the Custom Web Server option. But then a new error occurred; Visual Studio couldn't handle a folder having 24k+ files, which resulted in a crash. I was also unable to exclude these files from the pro^H^H^Hweb site, to prevent the crash.

Comment: That amount of files in a single folder can cause things other than Visual Studio to crash. Sounds like you need to redesign your solution.

Comment: Okay, this answer will have to do. Thank you.